# Is it possible to not have the FIFO bus messages respected with LogicApp?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a LogicApp which read messages from Azure Bus, and load/update/delete information on a table stored on Azure Data Warehouse.

I would like to know if it's possible to receive 2 messages to update the same row, and that the information of the second message arrives before the first one (because of a reason X or Y) => Consequently, the update of my DWH is not correct (the second update arrives first, so my DWH contains the update of the first message)

It's just need to know if I have to check during my update in the DWH if a new message is arrived after and my update is outdated or not.
I know that LogicApp had a FIFO queue, but I'm not sure that this rule is kept when I work with another platform, even called by LogicApp

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Messages in Service Bus are usually processed reliably by consumers one at a time but can opt for concurrent processing by having multiple consumers / threads. Logic Apps by default processes message concurrently.

You could ensure they are handled one after the other by either using [Message Sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions) or [trigger your Logic App sequentially](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-actions-triggers#trigger-instances-sequentially).